# why can i see any datas in the VuedevTools?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

there is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Demo1</title>
    <script src="./vue.js">Vue.config.devtools = true</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root">
        <h2>The weather is {{info}}</h2>
        <button @click="changeWeather">click to change</button>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    Vue.config.productionTips = false
    let vm = new Vue({
        el: '#root',
        data: {
            weather_status: true
        },
        computed: {
            info(){
                return this.weather_status===true ? 'sunny' : 'cloudy'
            }
        },
        methods: {
            changeWeather(){
                this.weather_status = !this.weather_status
            }
        }
        // watch:{
        //     immediate: true,
        //     info:{
        //         handler(nv,ov){
        //             console.log('The weather have changed from:',oldValue,'and now is:',newValue)
        //         }
        //     }
        // }
    })
    vm.$watch('info',(newValue,oldValue)=>{
        console.log('The weather have changed from:',oldValue,'and now is:',newValue)
    })
</script>
</html>
```

but while i open the devtools, it shows a bit different here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9PfW.png)
it have no data!! and i have searched for all of the question like me and got no answers.

so i want to get the reason and how can i fix this

Comment: Are you using the dev version of Vue and not the production bundle?